# designing citation style with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I writing a CV using latex. I use biblatex. I want to differentiate articles, proceedings, abstract and under review articles with different styles. I want list them like this and be able to reference them with the name given in this list:

**Journal Articles**

```
[J1] article published 1 
[J2] article published 2
```

**Proceedings**

```
[P1] proceeding 1
```

**Abstracts**

```
[A1] abstract 1
```

**Articles Under Review**

```
[U1] article under review 1 
[U2] article under review 2
```

Is there a way to do it with biblatex?

Answer (score 1):

Most of this is pretty straightforward if the `.bib` database is properly formatted.

The type of publication (article, book, proceedings, ...) can be filtered with the `type` option, which checks the entry type of the `.bib` entry.

If we want to distinguish published entries from work that is still under review, we can add the `keyword` `underreview` to entries under review and filter by that keyword as well.

`\newrefcontext[labelprefix=<prefix>]` makes sure to produce the desired letter before the numeric citation label. The option `defernumbers` is required for the correct numbering.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, defernumbers, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{appleby,
  author   = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title    = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  journal  = {Journal of the Civil Service},
  date     = {1980},
  keywords = {underreview},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson,worman,westfahl:space,nussbaum,cicero,moraux,salam,herrmann,appleby}

\printbibheading[title={List of Publications}]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography[type=article, notkeyword=underreview, heading=subbibliography, title={Articles}]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=P]
\printbibliography[type=inproceedings, notkeyword=underreview, heading=subbibliography, title={Proceedings}]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=B]
\printbibliography[type=book, notkeyword=underreview, heading=subbibliography, title={Books}]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=U]
\printbibliography[keyword=underreview, heading=subbibliography, title={Under Review}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Articles: [A1],[A2]//Proceedings: [P1],[P2]//Books: [B1],[B2],[B3]//Under Review: [U1]]

Comment: This approach kind of works but it replicates the entries in the bbl file for every call of the `\newrefcontext`. As a result, I get an error of: `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].` Is it normal?

Comment: @burak Yup that is normal, and I'm afraid there isn't a lot you can do about that. The only thing that comes to my mind is wrapping each `\newrefonctext` in a `\begin{refcontext}...\end{refcontext}` of its own and calling `\nocite` on the specific entries. You could also try LuaLaTeX, which has dynamic memory allocation. Are you sure though, that the TeX capacity exceeded is due to the number of entries in your bibliography? I have seen quite large bibliographies processed without problems. Maybe something else is off?

Comment: I guess the reason is I am keeping the abstracts of some papers in .bib file. I have tried to remove abstracts from the .bbl file just adding these to the code:

`\DeclareSourcemap{
 \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
  \map{
   \step[fieldset=abstract, null]
  }
 }
}`

and

`\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{abstract}}`

but both did not work. I am using a template created by someone else and there are a few lines which I don't know what they are doing. Maybe it is the reason.

Currently, I have solved the problem by creating a new .bib database by filtering my own research.